# Is Tall-Nut worth its price?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

Tall nut is one of my most used plants due to its high durability and the ability to block jumping/vaulting zombies. However, 2 wall nuts can do the same thing as 1 tall nut can and save you 25 suns, right? So should I keep using them or stop and use 2 wall nuts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tall-nuts have pros and cons to them. Personally, I use them instead of walnuts but your decision.

Pros:

- Take up less space than 2 wall-nuts, giving more defense area
- Recharges faster than 2 wall-nuts
- Pogo zombies can jump over the first one in a 2-wall-nut setup, but never tall-nuts.

Cons:

- As said by you, it costs 25 sun less to plant 2 wall-nuts
- 2 ladder zombies are needed to get through 2 wall-nuts, but only 1 for a tall-nut.

It's really your decision whether you use tall-nuts or not, however I advise you do.

Comment: I might be remembering wrong, but doesn't the Tallnut also block the pole vault zombies?

Comment: It boils down to whether you think you'll have more access to sunlight than garden plots.

Comment: @raznagul I haven't played in a long time, but IIRC the pole vault zombie only jumps the first wall nut and then gets stuck on the 2nd, attacking that one.

Comment: @Tim: IIRC, you are right. :)

Comment: Wasn't it, pogo zombies can jump over both wall nuts because his pogo stick can bounce multiple times, right?

Comment: I just remembered another con about the tall nut! It is that 2 ladder zombies are needed to get past the wall nut combo but only 1 ladder for a tall nut.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be a good strategy to use tall nuts. When I was playing they really helped out, I liked to plant them last after planting all my other plants, so I could just save up for them. Tall nuts can become very helpfull.

I think they're helpfull because they have more health then normal wallnuts. So zombies will just stand there and eat them as your other plants just destroy them.
So they act as a "slow down/protection barrier".

Comment: Well, 2 wall nuts have the same health as 1 tall nut which was what I was comparing. P.S. When you typed "I think there" the correct grammar is actually "I think they're".

Comment: I agree, I should've added that. I just got done playing and I noticed they regenerate faster than 2 wallnuts. All the more reason to use them. I'll check that grammer to.

Comment: @MelonPult They have "same" combined health but you will lose the first walnut when the "combined 2 walnuts" reach 50% health whereas the tall nut doesn't degrade unitl 0% health